# Yield usage in a lengthy process

Tags: c#, wpf

suppose i had a function like

```
public IList<type> Fetch()
{
       IList<type> list = new List<type>();
       //here comes a really long process and an item gets added to the list every few seconds
       return list;
}
```

now if i want to use this function as the following

```
//in a seperate thread
AnObjectThatHasADataboundProperty.ThatProperty = Fetch();
```

the above will have to wait for the Fetch() function to return a value but i want to update my view whenever an item is added, so i thought i should send that funcion a reference to the databound property, for example it would look like:

```
Fetch(AnObjectThatHasADataboundProperty.ThatProperty);
```

- is that how you would do it?
- i have never used `yield` before, is this a case where yield should
  be used?

Comment: which of GUI u have is it WPF or Winform

Comment: Use an ObservableCollection and bind to it.

Comment: @poke if i do so i still have to send the observablecollection property as a reference to the Fetch function then add to it?

Comment: @poke I didn't know there was such a class already available, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) type to directly make the view update whenever your collection changes. For example when you are using MVVM, then your view model can expose an observable collection, and you can then just bind to it from the view.

If you then update the collection from somewhere, the view automatically updates too.